# How to have a batch call itself to rerun, but wait 60 seconds before calling itself?

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I currently have a batch which calls itself if it finds records still falling into scope. I am using a static boolean variable to do this. Now i have found out our email system cannot handle thousands of emails within seconds, so they have advised me to send 50 emails a minute instead. I can swap the batch size to 50 easily however i am not sure how i can have the batch wait 1 minute before calling itself, if it still has records to process.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a specific method for this, [System.scheduleBatch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_scheduleBatch_section), which can be called from the finish method to chain indefinitely:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    System.scheduleBatch(new BatchClassName(), 'NextJobInChain', 1);
}
```

Where the second parameter should be a unique job name, and the third parameter is the number of minutes to wait.